# Converting Window-1252 to UTF-8 Issue

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have created a function to convert the following text to UTF-8, as it appeared to be in Windows-1252 format, due to being copied to a database table from a Word Document.

> Testing weird characterâ€™s correction

This seems to fix the dodgy `â€™` character. However i'm not getting � in the following:

> Devon�s most prominent dealerships

When passing the following through the same function:

> Devon's most prominent dealerships

Below is the code which does the converting:

```
function Windows1252ToUTF8($text) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
}
```

**Edit:**
The database can't be changed due to holding thousands of custom records. I tried the below but the `mb_detect_encoding` thinks `characterâ€™s correction` is UTF-8.

```
function Windows1252ToUTF8($text) {
    if (mb_detect_encoding($text) == "UTF-8") {
        return $text;
    }
    return mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Just tried the example from the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php):

```
$str = 'áéóú'; // ISO-8859-1
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')); // 'UTF-8'
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true)); // false
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

but this simply outputs:

> string(5) "UTF-8"
>   string(5) "UTF-8"

So I can't even detect the encoding of the string :S

**Edit 3:**
This seems to do the trick:

```
function Windows1252ToUTF8($text) {
    $badChars = [ "â", "á", "ú", "é", "ó" ];
    $match = preg_match("/[".join("",$badChars)."]/", $text);
    if ($match) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
    }
    return $text;
}
```

**Edit 4:**
I have matched the hex values to their corresponding values. However when I get to the weird characters they don't appear to match.

[image]

Comment: if you're trying to output from a database (which sounds like it to me), you need to pass UTF-8 in the connection before querying. Have you gone through this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?rq=1

Comment: If it's MSWord, it's probably a "smart" quote, i.e. the character `’`. This indeed results in � in the output.

Comment: See updated post @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: *"The database can't be changed due to holding thousands of custom records."* - Adding  UTF-8 to the connection parameter isn't "changing" a database, just the method of connecting to it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, just checked the database connection and this has already been added.

Comment: what about the file's encoding? This will matter. Try changing to ANSI, then UTF-8 (with and without BOM); one of those should pan out. I had the same problem before.

Comment: I mean i'm just testing this is one of the many PHP files which our websites run through, and the PHP File will be UTF-8. But the string from the database is not, which is the issue. In the past we have just done a load of string replacements, but it's a bit dirty that way. See updated post @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: I don't know how you're using that file to fetch/display, but this is what I had to do once when faced with a similar problem. `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');` on top, then `$file_x = "/path/to/file.xxx"; $file = file_get_contents("$file_x", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); $file = utf8_encode ( $file );` - I don't know if this will work for you. Did you try the file encoding comment I left earlier?

Comment: Hmm, couldn't seem to get it working. I have added my solution to my post, seems to work for now.

Comment: @MartynBall you should have posted that as an answer instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Good point, thanks for the help. Added the answer.

Comment: It's unclear whether the data is wrong, or you're interpreting the data incorrectly and that's the only reason it screws up. Show `echo bin2hex($theString)` to see what the actual bytes are, which allows us to judge how it needs to be converted if at all.

Comment: You're welcome @Martyn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Converting `Testing weird characterâ€™s correction` using bin2hex
>   gives me
>   `54657374696e6720776569726420636861726163746572c3a2e282ace284a27320636f7272656374696f6e`

This means the "â€™" is actually the bytes `\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2`. This is a typical sign of a UTF-8 string having been interpreted as Windows Latin-1/1252, and then re-encoded to UTF-8.

`’` (UTF-8 `\xe2\x80\x99`)
→ bytes interpreted as Latin-1 equal the string `â€™`
→ characters encoded to UTF-8 result in `\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2`

To restore the original, you need to reverse that chain of mis-encodings:

```
$s = "\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2";
echo mb_convert_encoding($s, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

This interprets the string as UTF-8, converts it to the Windows-1252 equivalent, which is then the valid UTF-8 representation of `’`.

Preferably you figure out at what point the encoding screwed up like this and you stop that from happening in the future. If it happened by "copy and pasting from Word", then basically somebody pasted garbage into your database and you need to fix the workflow with Word somehow. Otherwise there may be an incorrect encoding-conversion step somewhere in your code which you need to fix.

Comment: @Martyn I realise this basically is the same solution as you already found, but at least it provides a reason and gives you something to diagnose the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is very useful. I will mark this as the answer due to the information you have given me. I believe the issue does just stem from Word copy and pasting, we are working on backend systems to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do the trick. Not the way I wanted it to work by checking for specific characters, but it does the trick.

```
function Windows1252ToUTF8($text) {
    $badChars = [ "â", "á", "ú", "é", "ó" ];
    $match = preg_match("/[".join("",$badChars)."]/", $text);
    if ($match) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
    }
    return $text;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
function Windows1252ToUTF8($text) {
    // http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm
    $illegal_hex = [ "c3a2", "c3a1", "c3ba", "c3a9", "c3b3" ];
    $match = preg_match("/".join("|",$illegal_hex)."/", bin2hex($text));
    if ($match) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($text, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: What exactly this code does depends on the encoding the .php file is saved with. It's also a bad idea to try to treat encoding issues on an individual character basis. You need to figure out where exactly your encoding goes sideways and why, not just whack-a-mole like this.

Comment: @deceze that's the issue I was trying to solve. It's down to differently encoded values being pasted into the table.

Comment: They can't be "differently encoded", at worst they're *mojibake*. Which means you need to reverse the incorrect transcoding that happened at some point (and preferably prevent such transcoding from happening in the future). To do that you need to know what values exactly you're working with, for which you need to look at the actual bytes. → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885180/converting-window-1252-to-utf-8-issue#comment84776714_48885180

Comment: Converting `Testing weird characterâ€™s correction` using bin2hex gives me `54657374696e6720776569726420636861726163746572c3a2e282ace284a27320636f7272656374696f6e`

Comment: @deceze `e282`, `ace2`, `84a2` don't seem to correspond to a hex charset.